# How does Spring Security check @PreAuthorize and how does it call hasAuthority() method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

When I use Spring Security I found `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('authority_name')")`

How does Spring Security check `@PreAuthorize` and how does it call `hasAuthority()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security (`@PreAuthorize`) use a SPEL (Spring Expression Language) expression that invoke an Object returned from a `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`.

The default implementation for
`MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` is `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`. It create an instance of `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot` and then process the SPEL expression on it.

`MethodSecurityExpressionRoot` extends `SecurityExpressionRoot`, and that provides the `hasAuthority` method, that bekome invoked when you use it in a  `@PreAuthorize` Annotation.

Comment: It isn't recommended anymore to extend `SecurityExpressionRoot` instead just create a bean and call methods on it. In SpEL you can reference beans with `@beanName` so writing `@myHandler.myMethod` will invoke that method.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have any reference? - regarding the recommended to access the `Authentication` in that bean. (BTW - I have remove the additional part of my answer, so it only answer the question)

Comment: You can simply pass it as a method argument. The reference is the fact that the notion to write custom expressions by extending that class has dissapeared from the reference guide in Spring Security 4 and replace with a section on how to call custom methods. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-access-web-beans

Comment: Exactly M.Deinum we do that.
Like this:- 

    
@Component("securityService")
public class SecurityService {
 public boolean hasPermission(PermissionEnum... permissions) {

  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
    .getAuthorities();
  for (PermissionEnum permission : permissions) {
   if (authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.name()))) {
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }
   

and this is a good workaround.

Comment: Thanks  Ralph for your appreciation explain I do a little work with Spring Security can you support your explanation with references for more surrounding this topic.

Comment: devloper152: The Sourcecode for `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` is well written. Have a look on it. Once you know that class, any explaination will just only repeat the code.